# store database on hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

I'm learning Hadoop and Hive server, and I'm confused about something. Suppose I build a hadoop cluster with three machines, and I start storing images with a PHP/MySQL script.

Now for a MySQL database can I install Hive on the same Hadoop server or do I have to build another Hadoop server to store a MySQL database using Hive. Is it necessary to to separate a Hadoop file server and a Hadoop database server? Or can you store everything on the same Hadoop server?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your configuration, the answer is yes - both the Hive and Hadoop should exist on the same hardware.  Hive will talk to your Hadoop cluster configuration to create your database tables, schemas, etc.